# Append the package.json version number to my build artifact in aws-codebuild

Tags: aws-codebuild

I really dont know if this is a simple (must be), common or complex task.

I have a buildspec.yml file in my codebuild project, and i am trying to append the version written in package.json file to the output artifact.

I have already seen a lot of tutorials that teach how to append the date (not really useful to me), and others that tell me to execute a version.sh file with this
echo $(sed -nr 's/^\s*"version": "([0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}.*)",$/\1/p' package.json)

and set it in a variable (it doesn't work).
i'm ending up with a build folder called:   "my-project-$(version.sh)"

codebuild environment uses ubuntu and nodejs

Update (solved):
my version.sh file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    echo $(sed -nr 's/^\s*\"version": "([0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}.*)",$/\1/p' package.json)
```

Then, i just found out 2 things:

- Allow access to your *version.sh* file:

  **git update-index --add --chmod=+x version.sh**
- Declare a variable in any phase in buildspec, i dit in in build phase (just to make sure repository is already copied in environment)

  **TAGG=$($CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/version.sh)**

then reference it in artifact versioned name:

```
   artifacts:
     files:
       - '**/*'
     name: workover-frontend-$TAG
```

As result, my build artifact's name: *myproject-1.0.0*

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yeah, declaring a Var inside buildspec.yml (i declared it inside any build phase and it worked)
TAG=$($CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/version.sh)

then in artifact name
 name: myProjectName-$TAG

Answer (score 0):

In my case this script do not want to fetch data from package.json. On my local machine it working great but on AWS doesn't. I had to use chmod in different way, because i got message that i don't have right permissions. My buildspec:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    latestTag: ""
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - "echo sed version"
    - sed --version
  build:
    commands:
    - chmod +x version.sh
    - latestTag=$($CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/version.sh)
    - "echo $latestTag"
artifacts:
  files:
  - '**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
```

And results in console:
[CodeBuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmEP0.png)

I also have to mark that when i paste only for example `echo 222` into version.sh file i got right answer in CodeBuild console.